# exposing no argument shell script as network service

Tags: linux

I have an intranet connected system that needs to know if a process is running on my server but the users are not allowed to ssh to the server.   Ideally they could telnet to my server at port ##### and receive "up" or "down".  The port would be blocked to the internet so DOS attack should be mitigated.

```
#! /bin/bash
numprocs=ps -aef | grep myproc | wc -l 
if [[ numprocs > 1 ]]
then
     echo "up"
else 
     echo "down"
done
```

is there some tool that listens on port #### and will run my shell script, and return the output to whom ever connects to the port.

Comment: You can use `inetd` or its modern cousin `xinetd`

Comment: you meant `numprocs=$(ps -aef | grep '[m]yproc' | wc -l )`, didnt you? ;-) Good luck.

Comment: yes or 
numprocs=\`ps -aef | grep '[m]yproc' | wc -l\`

Comment: `if pgrep myproc` should be sufficient since you are not sending back the number of processes. You may want to look into `netcat`. I am not near a computer to write up a short code.